# Apple Wallet Pass local development with http url

Tags: ios, web-services, wallet, passkit

I finished setting up the webservice routes according to Apple documentation and I am able to sign and provide passes. Unfortunately I am experiencing the following problem. When I define the webServiceUrl as "https://localhost:5000/wallet/" the signing of the pass works as expected. I am then using the pass in the iOS Simulator where I have enabled the "Allow Http Services" in the developer settings but I am still getting the "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made" error. Trying then to use http instead of https directly in the definition of the webServiceUrl in the pass.json file produces a signing error. Do you know which steps have to be made to be able to test pass updates locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you everything you need to know.

Change your `webServiceUrl` to `http://localhost:5000/wallet/`.  The developer option means that you don't have to use https and the pass should still install on any device with "Allow Http Services" set.

Comment: I did that but then I cannot sign the pass. I am getting an exception. How can I sign a pass with *webServiceUrl=http://localhost:5000/wallet/* ? Does signpass binary from Apple work for you?

Comment: What library are you using to sign the pass?  You’ll need to override that exception as it is being imposed by your signing code, not by Apple.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/walletpass/pass-js . I am implementing my server using Node.js. Do you recommend an other library for Node.js?

Comment: No, I use my own golang library, but I am sure it would not be much trouble to manually edit your node package to remove the check while you test.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that but it is strange that Apple's official tool: signpass also produces an error when trying to sign a pass.json which contains an http endpoint for the webServiceUrl field

Comment: The source code to signpass is also available, so you could modify and recompile that to remove the restriction if you just need something to quickly test with.  The check is valid because production passes will not install if they contain a http `webServiceUrl`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. signpass seems to work without modification I retried now probably before was an other error. And yes it can be opened on a device with the developer setting "Allow Http Services" set to "true".

Answer (score 0):

Apple wallet passes do not support localhost URLs. Here are some of the tricks I tried -

1. Using computer IP address - This wouldn't work since I figured out apple wallet passes only support secure URLs.
2. Using ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) - Ngrok gives you a secure URL with it's port forwarded to your local development server. After installing ngrok on your mac, all you have to do is run `ngrok http 8080` in your terminal to get the secure URL.

I found this solution fairly simple. The only thing to keep in mind is to update the url every 2hr.